# IEnumerable<SelectListItem> in C# mvc

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, selectlistitem

I have two tables, Student (name, id, UniversityID) and Universities (Id, Name). One has the information about the student details and the other about the universities. In the first table I am storing the `Student.UniversityID` that matches with `Universities.ID`. The Universities are shown as a drop down in a form about the student details.

My question is when I am editing a specific student how to have the UniversityName choosen in the previous form while adding the student details, preselected.

What i am doing so far is that i am populating the dropdown like this

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = db.Universities
        .Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = c.UniversityId.ToString(),
            Text = c.UniversityName.ToString(),
            Selected = true,
        });
    ViewBag.UniversityID = items;
}
```

I guess the best thing to do is a join between the two tables based on the

*{select UniversityName from Universities Join Student where  Student.UniversityID=Universities.ID }*

Any idea how to do this join these two tables in Linq and to select the UniversityName that fits this contidition, using  IEnumerable SelectListItem???

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EntityFramework you can specify ForeignKey constraints, in which case you can just do:

```
db.Students.Select(student => new {
    UniversityName = student.University.UniversityName
})
```

To add ForeignKey constraints, in you EntityFramework data entity do:

```
[Table("Student")]
public class Student
{
    [Key] public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int UniversityId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UniversityId")] public University University { get; set; }
}
```